# GRUB menu when dual-boot with wubi "you need to lead the kernel first" nothing has worked so far

Tags: grub2, wubi

I'm a total noob at this so forgive me.

First of all i decided to install ubuntu using wubi and when i booted it using BIOS i got a grub menu, typing "boot" would just tell me "you need to load the kernel first", everything i've tried hasn't helped, any advice?

Comment: Welcome! It's better that you use the guide [Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) to create a bootable USB.

Comment: WUBI has been abandoned for years. Do not attempt to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WUBI is depreciated. Here's the way to do it:

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download .

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Make a LiveUSB on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0